# Joining on BETWEEN values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How do I do lookup or joining two tables based on the values of date?

In the first table I have `Item_ID` and `Entry_Date` as columns.
On the second one I have `Shift_ID`, `Personnel`, `Begin_Date`, and `End_Date` as columns.

I want to create a result that displays `Item_ID` and `Personnel`, where `Personnel` and `Shift` is determined by whether or not an Item's `Entry_Date` is between a shift's `Begin_Date` and `End_Date`.

[image: Example in Excel]

I'm sorry for utilizing image, I meant to write the table within this post itself but I don't know how yet.

Comment: It's easy to write properly looking tables. Just highlight the tables, and click `{}`. (Or have an empty row before, and 4 <space> first in each row.)

Comment: Do only tag the dbms actually used. (Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?)

Comment: When you copy tables from tools (database tool, Excel, etc.), you usually get a tab-separated list. There are tools to format such lists (e.g. https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/). Then paste the resulting formatted table in your request, highlight it and click then `{}` button.

Comment: As to your actual question: This is a basic join, so it is a tad hard to understand what you are having problems with. Do you think that you can only join on equality, like `some_column = some_other_column`? This isn't the case. You can join on whatever condition, e.g. `ON item.date >= shift.begin_date AND item.date <= shift.end_date`. (Using `BETWEEN` as shown by Tim is of course more convenient here.) You can use `=`, `<`, `<=`, `AND`, `OR`, `ÌN`, parentheses and many more operators in an `ON` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Try a basic join:

```sql
SELECT
    i.Item_ID,
    COALESCE(s.Personnel, 'NA') AS Personnel
FROM Item i
LEFT JOIN Shift s
    ON i.Entry_Date BETWEEN s.Begin_Date AND s.End_Date;
```